# Metrics not available when use istio-injection

Tags: kubernetes, istio-sidecar, metrics-server

I’m using metrics-server v0.6.3 in k8s v1.21.6, and istio 1.14.

If istio-injection to pod, error: Metrics not available for pod.

if not injection, metrics server running normally with pod.

Any one had this issue ? Please, help me fix this.

I think it had problem with metrics through istio-proxy cotainer.